# Drag drop and calculating width

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, drag-and-drop

I want to calculate and select drop area in my drag&drop application.

What I want to make:

1. When i drag box to top or bottom of the droppable div, width must be 100%
2. When i drag box to near the other box, (if one box in a row) their widths must be 50% - 50%
3. If a drag box and change place which box is already in wrapper, they must be calculated like that again.

[Here is my example code](http://jsfiddle.net/Kpp4x/)

```
$(".box").draggable({
    snap: '#droppable',
    snapMode: 'outer',
    revert: "invalid",
    cursor: "move",
    helper: "clone"
    //connectToSortable: "#droppable"
});

$("#wrapper").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var dropped = $(ui.draggable).clone();
        var droppedOn = $(this);
        $(dropped).detach().css({
            top: 0,
            left: 0
        }).appendTo(droppedOn);
        $(this).addClass("ui-state.highlight").find("p").html("");
    }
});
```

Can you please tell me the way how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: here is my expection : http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/222/dragdropsnap.png/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this [JQFAQ.com](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-set-calculated-width-in-drag-and-drop/) topic, this will help you to set the calculated width and we can drop the elements in specified area. There are few more sample FAQs too.